# How can i edit the default color theme and keyboard shortcuts in google colab?

Tags: google-colaboratory, keyboard-shortcuts, vs-color-theme-editor

I want to make a shortcut(ctrl+p) in colab to wrap all selected piece of text inside `print()` function. From the answer of this question titled : "Visual Studio Code Surround With", I have been able to do this in vscode. I want to achive same effect in google colab.

```
   {
        "key": "ctrl+p",
        "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
        "when": "editorTextFocus",
        "args": {
            "snippet": "print(${TM_SELECTED_TEXT})"
        }
    },
```

Moreover I also want to edit the default theme of colab so that when I create custom functions, the name of the function, wherever used always appears same color as built in types like - int, str, list, set etc.(green) and not white. How can I achive this?